# "tree package" for regression trees

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, cross-validation, decision-tree

Attempeting to run a 10 fold cross validation with the tree package in order to build out and test a regression tree, but am running into an error when creating the cv object, the error is

```
In cvdev + plearn$dev :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

not sure what could be causing the differing lengths, my code snipet is below

below is the code i am running to generate the CV/regression tree

```
data(Boston) #from ISLR2 package

set.seed(1)

train.ind <- sample (1:nrow(Boston), nrow(Boston)/2)
train <- Boston[train.ind,]
test <- Boston[-train.ind,]


tree.boston <- tree(medv~., data = train)
set.seed(1)
cv.boston <- cv.tree(tree.boston, k=10)
```

Comment: Where is this tree package to be seen in your code? Please include explicitly your libraries; see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

In function `cv.tree()` you must use an uppercase K as a parameter -
`cv.boston <- cv.tree(tree.boston, K=10)`

In addition, you can use the `summary` function:

```
> summary(tree.boston)

Regression tree:
tree(formula = medv ~ ., data = train)
Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] "lstat"   "rm"      "dis"     "tax"     "ptratio"
Number of terminal nodes:  10 
Residual mean deviance:  14.18 = 3445 / 243 
Distribution of residuals:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-12.78000  -2.06200  -0.07857   0.00000   1.80400  13.92000
```

And plot your tree:

```
plot(tree.boston)
text(tree.boston)
```

[image]